# Side-by-side institutes in latex beamer title page

Tags: latex, beamer

On the title page of my Beamer presentation, I have three authors, from two institutes. The authors get listed side-by-side, which is fine. Less fine is that the institutes get listed one on top of another in an oddly bulky column down the center. In other words, I get this:

```
                 My Talk Title

John Foo (1)     Sarah Bar (2)   Isaac Foo (1)

                Foo University
                Foo, MA, 02134

                Bar Institute
                Bar, CA, 90210
```

Whereas I'd love to have this instead:

```
                 My Talk Title

John Foo (1)     Sarah Bar (2)   Isaac Foo (1)

    Foo University         Bar Institute
    Foo, MA, 02134         Bar, CA, 90210
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here's the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

institute[Foo and Bar]{
  Foo University\\
  Foo, MA, 02134
  \and
  Bar Institute\\
  Bar, CA, 90210
}

\author{John Foo\inst{1} \and Sarah Bar\inst{2} \and Isaac Foo\inst{1}} 
\title[My Title]{My Talk Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]  % 'plain' suppresses header & footer decorations
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%% .. rest of presentation goes here

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not think that help is possible here without you showing code.  What template do you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this hack the stuff you want?

```
\institute[Foo and Bar]{
  \begin{tabular}[h]{cc}
      Foo University &  Bar Institute \\
      Foo, MA, 02134 &  Bar, CA, 90210
  \end{tabular}      
}
```